# Missing scroll in safari (MacOS)

Tags: html, css

I use overflow-y create scrollbar, but it's missing in safari (MacOS).

Please help, thank you very much.

```
.contentLeft{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**On chrome and firefox**

[image]

**On safari**

[image]

Comment: Looks like your object is being rendered less high in Safari. Use the element inspector to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying putting a  max-height or height value on it

```
.contentLeft {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height: 400px;
   /* height: 400px; */
 }
```

You can choose either max-height or height value, don't use both. choose

Comment: Please more details. Thank you.

Comment: i just edited the answer see if it answers your problem